# ZStack z-index offset on visionOS with Model3D views

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-zstack, visionos

If I take a ZStack and add a bunch of Model3D views to it (to arrange them in 2D space), the ZStack will give each successive view an adjustment to the z-axis, such that they appear to be placed on different planes. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place 3D models on the same Z-plane (in case that the pivot point of each model is in its center), use the same `depth` and `alignment` values for each ***Model3D*** view.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {  
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Model3D(named: "Scene", bundle: realityKitContentBundle)
                .frame(depth: 1.0, alignment: .center)
            
            Model3D(named: "Scene", bundle: realityKitContentBundle)
                .frame(depth: 1.0, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Also use z offset: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(z:)